# Have sub directory not be password protected using Apache's .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently on my server I have a .htaccess file in the root of my web directory -

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/root/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Economic Complexity Observatory"
Require valid-user`
```

And this works great properly password protecting my whole site. The only problem is that I have this one sub directory that I DON'T WANT to to be password protected. Is there a way to specify that one specific directory will be free of password protection?

Answer (score 19):

There is a way just using .htaccess. I saw this answer [elsewhere](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apache-remove-password-protection-subdirectory/)

Just create an .htaccess file in the non-password protected subdirectory with the content:

```
Satisfy any
```

and that's it.

It worked for me.

Comment: Doenst work for me somehow. I still get that auth popup for username and pwd input... On some browsers it works without problem. But for me with firefox and windows 7 it doesnt... Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to httpd.conf you can use the following (the "directory" directive cannot be used in .htaccess):

```
<Directory />
AuthUserFile /path/to/root/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Economic Complexity Observatory"
Require valid-user
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/unprotected/dir>
Satisfy All
</Directory>
```

I am not aware of a way to do it with htaccess without putting a separate .htaccess in each directory excluding the directory that should not be protected.

Comment: Had to use the "Any" instead of "All" i.e. my site.conf looks like:
`<Directory /path/to/unprotected/dir>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Satisfy Any
</Directory>`