# .htaccess, protect the root file without denying access to their childs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've developed a web application and I'm protecting it from direct access from browser using htaccess/htpasswd. What blocks me is that I want to protect the root directory of my application but not the files which are contained in it.
For example I have root folder 'A' and it contains folder 'B'. And under 'B' I have 'login.php'. I want that browser blocks me if I try "www.myapp.com/A/"
and allow access if I write "www.myapp.com/A/B/login.php". Regards

Comment: Change the file permissions on the server?

Comment: use the `!-f` conditional in your htaccess to do the rewrite as long as it's not for a file?

Comment: also I can provide an actual answer if you post what you currently have for .htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have sub directory not be password protected using Apache's .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280821/have-sub-directory-not-be-password-protected-using-apaches-htaccess)

Comment: How are you protecting your files at present?

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution. I just put the next line on the .htaccess file which is in the folder that i want allow access directly :

```
Require all granted
```

Thanks for All.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you want to HTTP 403 (assuming you're replicating an .htpasswd failure) anything that's **not** a file in your directory structure - you can do that by adding (something like) this to the .htaccess file in you docroot.

```
# this is just to be "on the safe side" and shouldn't be necessary
# also this requires Apache >= 2.4
DirectoryIndex disabled

# this will rewrite anything that's not a file to a 403 Forbidden
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* - [R=403]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this don't resolve my problem. The browser ask user/pass as soon as I introduce folder 'A'. Regards

Comment: You still want `Basic Auth` then (password request) on the files?